# Add items to a list from the thread that initialized it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library

I have a WPF application that communicate with the server via WCF.
I execute a method on the remote server and the callback method initializes a list with the results which running on a different thread. - This is fine and this is exactly the purpose of my application.

But when I want to add some more items to this list, it throws an exception that I can't add items from a different thread which has initialized this list.

```
public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemVM<T>> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        // This section runs on a separate thread.
        items = value;
        notify("Items");
        if (allItems == null)
            allItems = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemVM<T>>(items.Clone());

        // I want to save the current context here and use it on the AddItem method

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
        view.Filter = searchFilter;
    }
}

public void AddItem(ListBoxItemVM<T> 
{
    this.items.Add(item); // The following exception throws here
}
```

> Exception: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

I'm looking for some way to save the thread (or thread's ExecuteContext) that  the list was initialized with, and add items to that list with this thread/context.

It should be mentioned that there is nothing to do with the UI thread, I handled the marshaling with the UI thread on another region in my code.
I've tried to marshal the `this.items.Add(item);` code with the UI SynchronizationContext, buy they are different so it fails.

Thanks

Comment: Also you can try 'items.Dispatcher.Invoke' rather than 'this'

Comment: Yes you right, but I do want this section of code to run on a separate thread. Thank you.

Comment: Actually you can find dispatcher in some different objects, like you did before this.Dispatcher, listbox.Dispatcher, also there is Application.Current.Dispatcher. Are you tried all this and getting same error message ?

Comment: I can access the UI dispatcher in any region in my code since I've already saved it on a general static class, I use it in many regions in my code, that's not the problem. I don't need it here. The problem is that the list initialize's thread is X and the add item method runs in thread Y, but I want the Y to marshal with the X when it adds some items. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from .NET 4.5 there is a built-in mechanism to automatically synchronize access to the collection and dispatch CollectionChanged events to the UI thread. To enable this feature you need to call [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198861.aspx) from within your UI thread.

EnableCollectionSynchronization does two things:

Remembers the thread from which it is called and causes the data binding pipeline to marshal CollectionChanged events on that thread.
Acquires a lock on the collection until the marshalled event has been handled, so that the event handlers running UI thread will not attempt to read the collection while it's being modified from a background thread.
Very importantly, this does not take care of everything: to ensure thread-safe access to an inherently not thread-safe collection you have to cooperate with the framework by acquiring the same lock from your background threads when the collection is about to be modified.

Therefore the steps required for correct operation are:

1. Decide what kind of locking you will be using

   This will determine which overload of EnableCollectionSynchronization must be used. Most of the time a simple lock statement will suffice so this overload is the standard choice, but if you are using some fancy synchronization mechanism there is also support for custom locks.
2. Create the collection and enable synchronization

   Depending on the chosen lock mechanism, call the appropriate overload on the UI thread. If using a standard lock statement you need to provide the lock object as an argument. If using custom synchronization you need to provide a CollectionSynchronizationCallback delegate and a context object (which can be null). When invoked, this delegate must acquire your custom lock, invoke the Action passed to it and release the lock before returning.
3. Cooperate by locking the collection before modifying it

   You must also lock the collection using the same mechanism when you are about to modify it yourself; do this with lock() on the same lock object passed to EnableCollectionSynchronization in the simple scenario, or with the same custom sync mechanism in the custom scenario.

Comment: Thank you ! This is great answer & description. Thank you again :)